# Randomly generated number makes certain button highlighted

Tags: javascript

I'm building my first JS project and I want to generat a number from 1-100 and to add black border to one of 5 rectangles each representing a range of numbers (0-20, 20-40, etc). Unfortunately, the rectangles are highlighted randomly and don't appear to be tied to the generated number

Here what I wrote. How do I make this work properly?

```js
const makeNumber = () => {
  const randomValue = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  return randomValue;
};

test.addEventListener("click", function() {
  h1.innerText = makeNumber();
  statValue();
});

function remove() {
  stat.forEach((stat) => {
    stat.classList.remove("my-class");
    gif.style.visibility = "hidden";
  });
}

function statValue() {
  if (makeNumber() <= 20) {
    remove();
    normal.classList.add("my-class");
  } else if (makeNumber() > 20 && makeNumber() <= 40) {
    remove();
    stable.classList.add("my-class");
  } else if (makeNumber() > 40 && makeNumber() <= 60) {
    remove();
    warning.classList.add("my-class");
  } else if (makeNumber() > 60 && makeNumber() <= 80) {
    remove();
    overload.classList.add("my-class");
  } else if (makeNumber() > 80) {
    remove();
    critical.classList.add("my-class");
    gif.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

```css
.my-class {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="meter">
    <div class="stat normal"></div>
    <div class="stat stable"></div>
    <div class="stat warning"></div>
    <div class="stat overload"></div>
    <div class="stat critical"></div>
    <img class="gif" src="img/Blinking_warning.gif" alt="">
  </div>

  <h1>0</h1>
  <button class="btn">test</button>

</div>
```

Comment: There are a lot of variables that I don't see how they are maintained, like stat in the remove function, normal, stable, warning, critical, etc, in the statValue function.
You must add code functions on these for people to help you @Walter.

Comment: if you want direct access to div's then element with that id are available on global name space, not with class.

Answer (score 1):

Why are calling `makeNumber()` every time, everywhere? You need to save output of the `makeNumber()` in a variable and then run the loops against that variable. Because `makeNumber()`is being called in every `if-else` statement, it is generating new different random number and checking the new number against the condition. This is bound to give weird results.

You have assigned the output of `makeNumber()` to h1.innerHtml(??), but you are running if-elses with the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var random_number = 0;
  const test = document.getElementById("testBtn");
  const h1 = document.getElementById("testH1");
  const gif = document.getElementsByClassName("gif")[0];


  const makeNumber = () => {
    const randomValue = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    return randomValue;
  };


  test.addEventListener("click", function() {
    random_number = makeNumber();
    h1.innerText = random_number;
    statValue();
  });

  function remove() {
      document.querySelectorAll('.stat').forEach(function(e) {
      e.classList.remove("my-class");
      gif.style.visibility = "hidden";
  });
  }

  function statValue() {

    if (random_number <= 20) {
      remove();
      var normal = document.getElementsByClassName("normal")[0];
      normal.classList.add("my-class");
    } else if (random_number > 20 && random_number <= 40) {
      remove();
      var stable = document.getElementsByClassName("stable")[0];
      stable.classList.add("my-class");
    } else if (random_number > 40 && random_number <= 60) {
      remove();
      var warning = document.getElementsByClassName("warning")[0];
      warning.classList.add("my-class");
    } else if (random_number > 60 && random_number <= 80) {
      remove();
      var overload = document.getElementsByClassName("overload")[0];
      overload.classList.add("my-class");
    } else if (random_number > 80) {
      remove();
      var critical = document.getElementsByClassName("critical")[0];
      critical.classList.add("my-class");
      gif.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  }
  }, false);
```

```css
.my-class {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="meter">
      <div class="stat normal">Normal</div>
      <div class="stat stable">Stable</div>
      <div class="stat warning">Warning</div>
      <div class="stat overload">Overload</div>
      <div class="stat critical">Critical</div>
      <img class="gif" src="img/Blinking_warning.gif" alt="">
    </div>

    <h1 id="testH1">0</h1>
    <button class="btn" id="testBtn">test</button>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `makeNumber()` every time in `statValue()`, you can parse the created number from the click event. You can try this.

```js
const test = document.querySelector('.btn');
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
const stats = document.querySelectorAll('.stat');
const gif = document.querySelector('.gif');
const normal = document.querySelector('.normal');
const stable = document.querySelector('.stable');
const warning = document.querySelector('.warning');
const overload = document.querySelector('.overload');
const critical = document.querySelector('.critical');

const makeNumber = () => {
  const randomValue = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  return randomValue;
};

test.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const randomNumber = makeNumber();
  h1.innerText = randomNumber;
  statValue(randomNumber);
});

function remove() {
  stats.forEach((stat) => {
    stat.classList.remove("my-class");
    gif.style.visibility = "hidden";
  });
}

function statValue(randomNumber) {
  if (randomNumber <= 20) {
    remove();
    normal.classList.add("my-class");
  } else if (randomNumber > 20 && randomNumber <= 40) {
    remove();
    stable.classList.add("my-class");
  } else if (randomNumber > 40 && randomNumber <= 60) {
    remove();
    warning.classList.add("my-class");
  } else if (randomNumber > 60 && randomNumber <= 80) {
    remove();
    overload.classList.add("my-class");
  } else if (randomNumber > 80) {
    remove();
    critical.classList.add("my-class");
    gif.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

```css
.my-class {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="meter">
    <div class="stat normal"></div>
    <div class="stat stable"></div>
    <div class="stat warning"></div>
    <div class="stat overload"></div>
    <div class="stat critical"></div>
    <!-- <img class="gif" src="img/Blinking_warning.gif" alt=""> -->
    <img class="gif" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
  </div>

  <h1>0</h1>
  <button class="btn">test</button>
</div>
```